# Calculating minutes as from a decimal number

Tags: calculus, statistics

Let's say $h(p)$ gives me the number of hours I need to work as a function of a certain percentage $p$. I can input a percentage like $p = 5$ and it outputs $h(5) = 2.80$.

I'm able to convert it to the "minutes world" by taking the decimal part ($\alpha$) and using it to get the number of minutes $m = \frac{60\alpha}{100}$. In the case above 80 would represent 48 minutes.

But in order to do this I have to take the decimal part manually and convert it to minutes. Is there any single expression I could use, or at least a more elegant way, that I could apply right to $h(p)$ and having 2.48 right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematics we can use the floor or integer part function to take the largest integer that is smaller than a number. It is written $\lfloor x \rfloor$, for example $\lfloor 1.23 \rfloor = 1$

But what we want is what lacks from 1 to make it 1.23. We need to use subtraction.

We can use it in a function like this :

$$x\to f(x) = x  -\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$$
so for example
$$\begin{align}f(1.23) &= 1.23 - \lfloor 1.23\rfloor\\ &= 1.23 - 1.0 \\&= 0.23\end{align}$$

Now you can probably find out how to combine it with your division.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!